# JPIBootLoader is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: java, jvm, junit4, websphere-7

I am new to WebSphere Application Server.Getting this error in WAS Console while executing junit class (RunAs--> JUnit Test) 
[Running as Junit Test in Rational Application Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlRjO.png)

Actual Error Message is:
***JVMJ9TI001E Agent library D:\Program Files\IBM\SDPShared\plugins\org.eclipse.tptp.platform.jvmti.runtime_4.7.0.v201110280852\agent_files\win_em64t\JPIBootLoader could not be opened (D:\Program Files\IBM\SDPShared\plugins\org.eclipse.tptp.platform.jvmti.runtime_4.7.0.v201110280852\agent_files\win_em64t\JPIBootLoader is not a valid Win32 application. )
JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9jvmti24(-3): JVMJ9VM009E J9VMDllMain failed*** .

Came Across this below links and tried but can't able to resolve"
[link1-IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21319688)
[link2-IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_8.5.5/com.ibm.servertools.doc/topics/rprofilingenvvar.html)

I am using windows 10 64 bit, RAD 8.0.4 , WAS 7.0.23 ,Junit 4.12.
Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Junit running within the IDE's JVM? To check click on Run > Run Configurations, and look for the unit test you are trying to run. Then click on the JRE tab. It should show the Project Execution Environment.

Also, you're on a considerably old version of RAD and WAS. Any reason you can't upgrade?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kenny. Changed Project JRE(Websphere Application Server) to Execution Environment --> Run > Run Configurations > JRE Tab. Now it's working for me.